# Using Touchatag reader from C#?

Tags: c#, rfid, touchatag

I happen to have an old RFID reader from Touchatag. It's pretty old already but it seems to work fine. Unfortunately, Touchatag has stopped their support for this device and besides, it required an internet connection which doesn't make it a very practical solution...
What I would like to do is to use this device without the need for an internet connection and inside an application that's written in C#. Don't know what this app is going to do, but right now I'm investigating all the options that are available for this device. So, does anyone know a good C# library and other sources that allow me to use this device?
(Btw, this is purely experimental.)

Comment: Take a look at [tageventor](http://code.google.com/p/tageventor/). Maybe you can use some of that?

Comment: It looks interesting but it's Linux/Mac based. Still, interesting! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I know. I thought, maybe you can port some of the code, or at least see what's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any C# libraries of hand, but you can check out either:

### IOTOPE

Java project that includes a low level library and a more high-level interface to the reader. You can probably adapt it to provide an interface to your C# application.

- See http://blog.iotope.com/node/quick-starter/

### libnfc

Low level NFC library. Mostly targeted for unix like systems, but could be put to work on windows as well.

- See https://code.google.com/p/libnfc/

Answer (score 1):

If you're experimenting with RFID, rather than works the bugs out of interfacing with a custom reader, you can buy a cheap USB RFID reader for around 10 £/$/€

A lot of them simply act like a keyboard and 'type' characters into your application (some even add a carriage return which is handy)

Comment: True, but I already have this hardware so basically I would just have to throw it away. I don't like to waste my electronic hardware that way. It's a good alternative, though. :-)